# Phrase for wearing clothes that lack any taste, style, distinctiveness, shape, or anything

Tags: phrase-requests

I am looking for a phrase for wearing clothes that lack any sort of style, fashion, expressiveness, or anything beyond their basic function. This does not mean that the clothes are disfunctional (as in holes) or socially inappropriate (as in Hawaii shirt in your business meeting). Maoist uniforms come close in being featureless, but even those have got a least a "message" or "meaning".

Perhaps 'burlap sack' comes close to what I am looking for.

> Those school uniforms are so plain –
>    why did they pick such _______

Comment: There is *frumpy* but that tends to be used exculsively for women and doesn't quite match your requrements.

Comment: 'Dull' and 'unfashionable' can both be used, but using both together sounds more idiomatic to my ears: 'Those school uniforms are so plain – why did they pick such a dull and unfashionable design?'

Comment: Your question says 'phrase for wearing clothes....', but your example sentence begs a word describing the clothes, not the act of wearing them. Which do you want?

Comment: @Spagirl: Right. I leave that deliberately open. Either is useful for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest *shapeless* and *drab*.

> **[drab](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/drab)**
>
> (adj) boring, especially in appearance; having little colour and excitement:
>
> - *I feel so drab in this grey uniform*.
>   <sub>Cambridge Dictionaries</sub>

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drab) defines the term as follows

> **2.b** (noun) a dull, lifeless, or faded appearance or quality
>
> **4.** (adjective)  not bright or colorful : too plain or dull to be interesting

Thus the school children's uniforms could be described as *drabs*, or looking *drab*.

> 1.Those school uniforms are so plain – why did they pick such **shapeless drab** clothes?
> 2. Those school uniforms are so plain – why did they pick such **drabs**?

Comment: Does 'dross' get a look in? I've never knowingly seen any, but it's supposed to the very worst quality of cloth available…

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin it hadn't occurred to me. You should post it as an answer. it's a good suggestion.

Comment: Thanks Mari-Lou and my main hesitation is that 'dross' describes the raw cloth… it could still pick up same style from the pattern.